# error "Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>`" in react jsx class

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I created a new functional class with jsx, but I'm getting an error. I'm new to it, but I haven't been able to find an effective solution. How can I fix it?

Hello.jsx class:

```
import React from "react";
const Hello = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello
    <div/>
  );
};
export default Hello;
```

I'm sharing it visually to be clear:
[image]

if it is on the screen, I get an error like this: "Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>`."

Answer (score 1):

It means that a return is not nessacry and you should shorten your code to be like so:

```
import React from "react";
const Hello = () => 
 (
    <div>
      Hello
    <div/>
  );

export default Hello;
```

Comment: I have tried this technique but this is also useless , didn't get rid of the error .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Babel Extension]

If you have installed Babel extension in your VS Code editor then uninstallation of Babel will help you to resolve the error .